# Embedding j2v8 library in neo4j and reuse of the V8 runtime

Tags: java, neo4j, java-threads, j2v8, neo4j-plugin

I need to embed [j2v8-4.6.0 library](https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8) (bindings for JavaScript engine, V8) for use in [neo4j-community-3.1.0](https://neo4j.com) (graph database management system) user-defined functions.

So, code of my simple plugin:

```
package js;

import org.neo4j.procedure.*;
import com.eclipsesource.v8.*;

public class J2V8
{

    public static V8 v8 = V8.createV8Runtime();

    @UserFunction("js.eval")
    @Description("js.eval(code) - eval the given javascript code.")
    public String eval( @Name("code") String code) 
    {
        if (code == null) code = "";
        try {
            int result = v8.executeIntegerScript(code);
            return result + "";
        } catch (final Exception se) { return se.toString(); }
    }

}
```

The plugin is compiled and installed correctly. And the first call of the user function `js.eval` occurs without error. But a second call (as well as all of the following) gives an error:

```
Failed to invoke function `js.eval`: Caused by: java.lang.Error:
Invalid V8 thread access
```

I have read that [J2V8 enforces single threaded](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/getting-started-with-j2v8/) and all access to a single runtime must be from the same thread.

This means that every time when call a user function, it is necessary to create the runtime (`V8.createV8Runtime`). But this is a costly operation.

So the question is: how to avoid the need to create the V8 runtime every time when call a function, and reuse once created V8 runtime?

Comment: You tried using a synchronized singleton?

Answer (score 0):

You can release the Locker after finish execution and acquire Locker again before execution.

```
if(v8==null) createV8Runtime();
v8.getLocker().acquire();
// execute your js here
v8.getLocker().release();
```